# Cloud firestore unable to deploy delete user function from project

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

Error: "Cloud Fire Error: functions predeploy error: Command terminated with non-zero exit code 1"

I have a view all users screen in my application. On this screen, I have access to both email and uID. I need to build functionality that I can click a delete user button on the users tile. This should then delete the user from firebase authentication and the users collection in firebase. I seen from other posts that the best way for this would be to create a cloud function which I have tried from firestore documentation. I am getting the below error. The code I am trying is from firestore documentation and is as follows:

```
getAuth()
  .deleteUser(uid)
  .then(() => {
    console.log('Successfully deleted user');
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log('Error deleting user:', error);
  });
```

Attaching documentation link - https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#node.js_7

[image]

Any advice is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit upon reading your question again:**

This isn't a direct answer to your question but just a few things to note...

You essentially have 2 options here - deleting the user form the front end or firebase functions - each is slightly different.

Front end - You need to pass the user object into `deleteUser()` not the user's uid, and vice versa passing in the uid.

Firebase function example:

```
  return admin.auth().getUserByEmail(data.email).then(user => {
    return admin.auth().deleteUser(user.uid);
  }).then(() => {
    return {
      massage: `Success, ${data.email} has been deleted.`
    }
  }).catch(err => {
    return err;
  });
```

Front end example:

```
import { getAuth, deleteUser } from "firebase/auth";

const auth = getAuth();
const user = auth.getUser(uid)

deleteUser(user).then(() => {
  // User deleted.
}).catch((error) => {
  // An error ocurred
  // ...
});
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#delete_a_user

Comment: I don't want to delete the current user I want to basically pass either an email or UID as a lecturer and delete a student I have a view which shows all users and have a delete button beside each user. Is this possible with authentication or can you only delete the current user?

Comment: Updated the example

Answer (score 0):

This may happen because:

- You don't have eslint installed. This could happen if at the time you ran `firebase init functions` you answered no when prompted `Do you want to use ESLint to catch probable bugs and enforce style?` and/or you answered no when prompted to install dependencies. If that's the case reinitialize the environment to get it installed.
- You're missing the eslint package in your package.js file. To check/fix this open it up and look if you have something in the lines of:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^4.12.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^3.6.0"
  },
```

- As stated by @Werner7, that is also a possible solution.

Comment: Where is the package.js file located? Inside the functions folder I have a folder called eslintrc.js, when doing the setup selected yes for all options

Comment: Package.js is located at the root of your folder. Thanks for the additional information